# Delphi TidTcpClient byte array

Tags: sockets, delphi, tcpclient, delphi-10.1-berlin

How to receive byte array by client? 
Old versions had `ReadBuffer()`.

But berlin 10.1 has not this function. So how can i do this?

My code:

```
var buf:tidbytes;
begin
 priborloadform.IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadBytes(buf,*integer*,true);
end;
```

UPDATED

What integer value must be there in the case when i don't know count of bytes i need to read previously.

Comment: So, what's wrong with calling `ReadBytes`?

Comment: In Indy 10, `TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes()` is indeed the newer replacement for the older `TIdTCPConnection.ReadBuffer()` method in Indy 9. If you need to copy the `TIdBytes` data to another memory location, you can use the `BytesToRaw()` function in the `IdGlobal` unit. Alternatively, if you want to avoid the intermediate `TIdBytes`, you can use a `TIdMemoryBufferStream` (also in the `IdGlobal` unit) with the `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` method.

Comment: What *integer* value must be there? 
I don't know how much bytes is there previously